# How to display an actual image in ListView rather than its location?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have found this code to add picture to a ListView in WPF. However it only displays the image location rather than the actual image:

```
            var image = new BitmapImage();

            string fileName = @"C:\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\slides_png\slide1.png";

            using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.StreamSource = stream;
                image.EndInit();
            }


            ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
            Thumbnails.Items.Add(image);
```

The XAML behind is simply:

```
<ListView Name="Thumbnails" Margin="10,10,804,10" >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>



 </ListView>
```

I also found few other codes, but all of them just show the image location as string rather than image. Can you please help me solve this?

Comment: You instanciate a new `ListBoxItem`, but do nothing with it. Isn't something missing ?

Comment: Sorry, that line was extra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `BitmapImage` as `ListViewItem`, which is not visual (so it doesn't renders) and displayed as `ToString()`.

Normally you should use `DataTemplates` in such cases, but this should works for you too:

```
var fileName = @"C:\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\slides_png\slide1.png";
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName)) { /*.. more bitmap image options if you like .. */ };
var image = new Image() { Source = bitmap /*.. more image options ..*/ }
Thumbnails.Items.Add(image);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it complains about this line:

Comment: var bitmap = new BitmapImage(fileName);

Comment: it says "invalid argument"

Comment: @user1394252, forgot to put path into `Uri`, see edit.

Comment: I just have one additional question. Now that I have the list populated the way I want it, how to make each image appear in another text box or some other wpf element when each thumbnail is clicked in ListView?

Comment: @user1394252, this is a whole new question. You will have to use bindings to populate list box: `ItemsSource` have to be bound to collection of e.g. paths (see @Clemens answer) and `SelectedItem` to some property. When you click thumbnail in `ListBox` it will get selected in list box -> `SelectedItem` will change -> binding source property will be updated -> other controls can bind to `SelectedItem` (and use `DataTemplate` as well to display it in a way you want) and as a result will display clicked thumbnail elsewhere.

Comment: Can't I just simply copy somehow the content of each element from the list to the content of StackPanel that is going to show each image on mouse click?

Comment: @user1394252, yes, you can. Simplest (very winform-like solution) is to subscribe to [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and do something there. You can use `DataContext` of selected item to get `Image` from `ListViewItem`. In wpf however we are using bindings and you will like it once you start using it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be added to the XAML :

```
        <ListView  x:Name="lv" Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                   Height="500" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding models}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                       Stretch="Fill" 
                                       Height="100"
                                       Width="100"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Yow need a model for this :

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private Uri _ImagePath;
public Uri ImagePath
{
    get
    {
        return _ImagePath;
    }
    set
    {
        _ImagePath = value;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImagePath"));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

}

And an example for the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public Model ImageModel { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ImageModel = new Model();
    ImageModel.ImagePath = new Uri(@"/ImageSource;component/Images/Image1.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    this.DataContext = ImageModel;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ImageModel.ImagePath = new Uri(@"/ImageSource;component/Images/Image2.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

}

This is the easiest and fastest way to tackle this issue. If you need MVVM just raise a hand and we can get a Command instead of that Click event. One more thing, do you have a list of images? If so, we will have to use an ObservableCollection and instantiate many models in order to feed all the Buttons.

- ImageSource is my assembly name.
- Images is a folder created in my project.

In order to populate the ListView you need an `ObservableCollection<Model>` defined like this :

```
      public ObservableCollection<Model> models { get; set; }
```

Initialize it in the constructor :

```
      models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
```

and add some Model instances to it with their image path set as shown above.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have a folder with about 20 images that I would like to add to the list dynamically.

Comment: @user1394252 Iterate over your files, get their path, Instantiate a Model object for each one and set its ImagePath. Add every new object to the models ObservableCollection<Model>. The binding is already made via the ItemsSource property in the XAML, DataContext is set in the constructor..

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a DataTemplate that actually displays the BitmapImage objects:

```
<ListView Name="Thumbnails" ... >
    ...
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Without the DataTemplate a ListViewItem just shows the output of the `ToString()` method of the data items.

---

Then (without any MVVM) an easy way to show all PNG files in a folder would be this:

```
Thumbnails.ItemsSource = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\slides_png", "*.png")
    .Select(f => new BitmapImage(new Uri(f)));
```